# Not Getting New Update is Available Notification in google play for my application

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I Published an application in google play . But the thing is if i released an updated version of my Application the users who is having the older version are not getting any Notification from google play that New Update is available. If they go to the google play there they can see an option like Update.

Even though i increased the Version Code in the Manifest File.

This became a very big problem to me . So please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if, as a developer, you can do much about that. You have done what you could as one (a developer) and updated the app. The issue _I suspect_ lies with the Google Play app not notifying the user of an updated app's availability. That is something you can do nothing about. And I doubt it is specific to your app. I saw an update to the Google+ app only after I opened the Google Play app and went into the _My apps_ section.

Comment: Yes Even if i went went to MyApps Section there i can able to see my App under Update Category.

Comment: If you have recently published the update and head into Google Play app to look for it, it almost never happens. It takes a little time to percolate through their systems. The same applies for a notification for the availability of an update for any app. It can take a few minutes to a few hours for the update to be available everywhere. Give it some time do it's thing. It will appear everywhere when the process completes. _Again, there isn't much you can do about it, except, pretty much, wait_. :-(

Answer (score 0):

U will have to program this yourself.

U can find how to do it on this link:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

if read correctly u have to release a new version of youre app with this code in it. users who have that version get notifications in case there is another update